# Using a return value as variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a JavaScript that sends for information and return it to a div. I works fine but I want to make the div id variable dependent on what's in the return. For instance:

```
function autoSubmit3() {
    $.post(
        'updatetype.php', 
        $('form[name="reportform"]').serialize(), 
        function (output) {
            $('#update').html(output).show();
        }
    );
}
```

Would become,

```
function autoSubmit3() {
    $.post(
        'updatetype.php', 
        $('form[name="reportform"]').serialize(), 
        function (output) {
            $('#4update').html(output).show();
        }
    );
}
```

If the "4: Type updated." were returned.

The target div is

```
<div id="' . $Count . 'update"></div>
```

On the 'updatetype.php' page is

```
echo $Count, ": Type updated.";
```

Comment: What is the question? You have only stated what you want to do. not what you have tried, or where you are having issues.

Answer (score 0):

"I want to make the div id variable dependent on what's in the return"

You can dynamically change the id of the div using something like this (with JQuery):

```
$('#2update').attr('id',newNumber+'update');
```

Rough example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pnellesen/9sWzj/)

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood:

```
function autoSubmit3() {
    $.post(
        'updatetype.php', 
        $('form[name="reportform"]').serialize(), 
        function (output) {
            var id = parseInt(output); // or anything you want to get the number
            $('#' + id + 'update').html(output).show();
        }
    );
}
```

Actually, give a look at [nth-child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) and [eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/), it could be easier.

Answer (score 0):

This might be something you're looking for. (without all the ajax stuff)

**php**

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
foreach ($array as $index => $value) {
    echo '<div id="' . $index . '_item">' . $value . '</div>';
}
```

**javascript**

```
'use strict'
var index = 2; // get your index 
var id = '#' + index + '_item';
var element = $(id); // do your stuff with it
```